# Does$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ always hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

It is fairly obvious that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}a_nb_n\leq \sum_{n=1}^{k}a_n\sum_{n=1}^{k}b_n$$
is true for all finite $k$ and positive $a_i,b_i$, but even if 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$$
converges we are not guaranteed that either of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \ \ \text{or} \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$$
does. I want to use this fact in a proof that a normed space with a Schauder basis is separable, so in my case we can assume that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$ does in fact converge. I still don't know if that is enough though. In fact I think it most probably isn't but I'd like to confirm.

P.S I know that there is a another post on MSE with a proof for separability following from the existence of a Schauder basis, which most probably doesn't use the above "fact", but I like to bump around in the dark and learn some things before looking at the solutions of others.

Comment: Are you assuming all the $a_i,b_i$ are nonnegative?

Comment: Yes, I think I put that in somewhere.

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ or $\sum b_n$ diverges then they diverge to infinity (since all terms are positive) so yes it holds true in this case also (finite-number $< \infty$).

Comment: OK. The partial sums each converge, but possibly to $\infty$. Just take limits on both sides of the inequality with the partial sums.

Comment: Ok thank you all. That's clear enough. Unfortunately I've just realised though, that in my argument I can't actually guarantee that each $b_i>0$ so the point has become moot. I shall leave the post open though so if anyone else needs this for some other reason it's here.